# How to add class/ID to any element?

Tags: html, drupal, dom, drupal-7

I'm having trouble finding a concise answer or help to this. I want to be able to add a class or ID to **ANY** element in Drupal. So to make it easy for a button on a page, I want to add the class "button". How and where is this done? I see a reference in the form.inc, and using something like module.php but im struggling to get some concrete help.

Comment: What version of Drupal is this for?

Comment: Drupal 7.10. Sorry for not putting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement overrides for the core themes that provide the markup for form items. These include [`theme_button`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_button/7), [`theme_submit`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_submit/7), [`theme_textfield`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_textfield/7) and loads more besides.

To do this, implement `MYTHEME_theme_name()` in your active theme's template.php file and override the output as you see fit:

```
function mytheme_button(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'submit';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value'));

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'];
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['disabled'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-button-disabled';
  }

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-new-class';

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

The above function is copied directly from `theme_button()` function and just adds an extra line to add an extra class to the button element.

Make sure you clear Drupal's caches once you implement the hook so the theme registry will pick it up.

It's worth noting the Drupal already adds classes like `form-text`, `form-submit`, etc to individual elements so you could try to use those if you're trying to target elements with CSS.

Comment: Wow. Yeah the force is not that strong with me yet. I'm trying to use the twitter/bootstrap CSS and so i thought it was going to be "relatively" easy to do. I'll mess around and see how far I can get.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the element you wish to alter. 
For example you can add classes and id"s to forms with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).
Other elements have to be altered or overruled inside your custom theme templates, depending on where the element comes up it can be in e.g. html.tpl.php, page.tpl.php, block.tpl.php, node.tpl.php and so on.
With the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and the [Devel themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) modules you can have a better opinion of where to look.

Edit: BTW never hack into core this will get you in a lot of trouble later on!

Answer (score -1):

Go through `page.tpl.php` in `sites/all/themes/yourthemes/...` and you can put id or classnames as your wish.